# Minio console not accessible behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, minio

I am trying to redirect a `example.com/minio` location to minio console, which is run behind a nginx proxy both run by a docker compose file. My problem is that, when I'm trying to reverse proxy the minio endpoint to a path, like `/minio` it does not work, but when I run the `minio` reverse proxy on root path in the nginx reverse proxy, it works. I seriously cannot findout what the problem might be.

This is my compose file:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio/:/data
    command: server /data --address ':9000' --console-address ':9001'
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio_admin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio_123456
    ports:
      - 9000
      - 9001
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: 20m
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
```

My nginx configuration is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # To allow special characters in headers
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
    # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # To disable buffering
    proxy_buffering off;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/service-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/service-error.log debug;

    location / {
        return 200 "salam";
        default_type text/plain;
    }
    location /minio {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_pass http://minio:9001;
    }
}
```

The picture I'm seeing of minio console at the domain is this:
[image]

And the response of curling the endpoint (`$ curl -k http://example.com/minio`):

```xml
<null>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <base href="/" />
            <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
            <meta content="#081C42" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" name="theme-color" />
            <meta content="#081C42" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" name="theme-color" />
            <meta content="MinIO Console" name="description" />
            <link href="./styles/root-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="./apple-icon-180x180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" />
            <link href="./favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png" />
            <link href="./favicon-96x96.png" rel="icon" sizes="96x96" type="image/png" />
            <link href="./favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png" />
            <link href="./manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
            <link color="#3a4e54" href="./safari-pinned-tab.svg" rel="mask-icon" />
            <title>MinIO Console</title>
            <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.eec275cb.js"></script>
            <link href="./static/css/main.90d417ae.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
            <div id="root">
                <div id="preload">
                    <img src="./images/background.svg" />
                    <img src="./images/background-wave-orig2.svg" />
                </div>
                <div id="loader-block">
                    <img src="./Loader.svg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also struggled with this for a long time and was finally able to resolve it.

As far as I can tell, the key changes to make this work for me where:

- Manually specifying a `rewrite` directive (instead of relying on the Nginx proxy_pass+URI behaviour which didn't seem to work for me).
- Setting the `resolver` directive with short timeouts (so that rescheduling of services onto other nodes gets resolved).
- Setting `$upstream` to prevent DNS caching.

I had to change your setup a little bit so that now the Minio S3 API is served behind `minio.example.com` while the UI Web Console is accessible at `minio.example.com/console/`.

I have edited your config files below:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio/:/data
    command: server /data --address ':9000' --console-address ':9001'
    environment:
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: "http://minio.example.com/"
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: "http://minio.example.com/console/"    
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio_admin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio_123456
    ports:
      - 9000
      - 9001
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: 20m
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
```

**nginx.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name minio.example.com;

    # To allow special characters in headers
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
    # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # To disable buffering
    proxy_buffering off;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/service-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/service-error.log debug;


    # Use Docker DNS
    # You might not need this section but in case you need to resolve
    # docker service names inside the container then this can be useful.
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

    # Apparently the following line might prevent caching of DNS lookups
    # and force nginx to resolve the name on each request via the internal
    # Docker DNS.
    set $upstream "minio";

    # Minio Console (UI)
    location /console/ {

        # This was really the key for me. Even though the Nginx docs say 
        # that with a URI part in the `proxy_pass` directive, the `/console/`
        # URI should automatically be rewritten, this wasn't working for me.
        rewrite ^/console/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://$upstream:9001;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        # To support websocket
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;    
    }


    # Proxy requests to the Minio API on port 9000
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://$upstream:9000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        # To support websocket
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    }

}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 4):

minio doesn't work under non default path like location /minio

You need to use
location / {
....
proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
}
or add another server block to nginx with subdomain like this

```
server{

listen 80;

server_name minio.example.com;;

     location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

       proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
   }
}
```

Comment: I need it to work under a subpath really, but since it's not possible I have to accept your answer. Hopefully someday it will work out!

Comment: Sadly I came to the same conclusion after 4 months... The furthest I got is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.069a61a0.js:1:1)`  in browser console when you set `MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL` to match reverse proxy path. Atop of reverse proxy I also need SSL.

Comment: I've hit a similar issue where the wss://host:9001/ws/objectManager is giving me a 403. While I've yet to find the real answer to this issue, this specific SO answer goes against the Minio Docs: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html

Comment: minio does work under non default path like location /minio. Just need to add the browser redirect url setting to minio server
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76760911/2018712

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have configured minio server with the browser redirect url to reflect your sub path.

This can be set as environment variable like

```
MINIO_SERVER_URL="https://yourdomain.com"
MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL="https://yourdomain.com/your_subpath"
```

Ref :https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You can't proxy the API under a `/path` but you certainly can proxy the UI under a path

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/arschles/minio-howto/blob/master/setup-Nginx-proxy-with-Minio-Server.md

if you use a nginx docker container, add this file to /etc/nginx/conf.d and remove the existing default.conf file in same directory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31987919)

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question, it does not install to a specific path.